# Single MSI for Install, Upgrade and Patch

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer, upgrade, patch

Is it possible to handle Install, Upgrade and Patch through a single MSI, may be by passing arguments or switches. My client has a requirement. Has anyone faced this in the past? Can anyone please help and provide some links substantiating this?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can have upgrade option in MSI. In WIX, it is automatically added by default when you create a project, unless you explicitly remove it. Please refer to `<MajorUpgrade>` element. Here is corresponding HOWTO in the documentation:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/updates/major_upgrade.html

As for the "patch" part - probably you meant something else. Windows installer patch files even have a different file extension - `.msp` (and different format). Usually creating patch files makes sense only for very big installs (something like gigabytes in size). You might want to clarify this part with your client.